# Select only email from a message- Open Refine

Tags: openrefine

I have columns with several cells like this:

```
"Hi my email is mail@mail.com feel free to email me!"

"Hey, this is my email: mail2@mail.com"
```

I want to create a new column from there with this cells:

```
"mail@mail.com"

"mail2@mail.com"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can search the for mail adresses with regex (take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression)). An easy example for such a regex would be `/\b\S+@\S+\.\S+\b/`

To use it in OpenRefine:

- Click on column
- "Edit column"
- "Add column based on this column…"
- set "New column name"
- set "Expression" with something like `value.find(/\b\S+@\S+\.\S+\b/)[0]`
- Ok